# How to filter a list in a dictionary by the key and values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I got a very big dictionary with lists in it called traffic. Here is a small example of my dictionary:

```
{'redlights': [{'id': 32,
'userid': '3',
'time': '2013-09-T17:12:00+05:00',
'calls': 1,
'crossings': '0',
'bad_behaviour': '0',
'senior': False,
'cat': False,
'dog': True,
'hitrun': 'David Williams'},
{'id': 384,
```

So, I called it hello as a test. I want all the keys within the list redlights that has 'senior' in it with value 'False'. I first tried this dict comprehension to get all the keys with senior in it:

```
hello = traffic['redlights']
new = {key: value for key, value in hello.items() if key == senior}
```

But then I got this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Probably because it's a list, but I don't know how I can get the keys that has senior in it with the value false. It has to be in the redlights list because the other lists are not relevant. How do I do this in a dict comprehension?

Comment: `hello` is not a dictionary, it's a list of dictionaries. `new = [item for item in hello if not item['senior']]`

Comment: Because `['redlights']=["List with dictionary inside"]`.

Comment: So then I selected a dictionary within that list right? Why did I still get that error then?

Comment: @taaaaavi Because `list` has no method called `items`.

Comment: Because you're using a dictionary comprehension on a list, which inherently doesn't have key/value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hello` is not a dictionary, it's a list (of dictionaries) and lists don't have `items`. You have to iterate over each of the dictionaries in the list. 
 This example will get the `id` of each dictionary with `senior=False`.

```
res = [d['id'] for d in hello if not d['senior']]
```